# React, conditional styling for style-components won't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have looked for dozens of examples on google and youtube but none of them seems to work. My problem is that whenever I try classic methods for conditional styling in styled-components it won't change the component's style as I wish it to change... Anybody can tell me what I am doing wrong?

Child component:

```
 const Ripple = styled(ButtonBase)`
  font-family: ${font.family};
  font-size: ${(props) => (props.small ? '14px' : '16px')};
  color: white !important;

  &:focus {
    border-radius: 6px;
  }
`;
```

Parent:

```
<Button small label="Get in touch" href="/" />
```

It does nothing.... Pls help.

Comment: But the component that you're rendering is `<Button>`, you should use `<Ripple>`

Comment: `function Button(props) {
  return (
    <Ripple href={props.href} focusRipple>
      <Box>{props.label}</Box>
    </Ripple>
  );
}

export default Button;`

Comment: The code above is the component I am rendering .... Ripple is just a styled-component "class" for one of the elemtents/layers of the component itself

Comment: You need to add the prop `small` to the `<Ripple>` not the parent only, otherwise it will not work, e.g. `<Ripple small ...etc>`

Comment: Ok.. and but that keeps my button always small since its in the child component. I want to set that props always from a parent - it going to be a button of sm/md/lg variants

Comment: I understand, but that would be a different question, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be calling the wrong component. You're calling `<Button />`

Try:

```
<Ripple small label="Get in touch" href="/" />
```

Comment: `function Button(props) {   return (     <Ripple href={props.href} focusRipple>       <Box>{props.label}</Box>     </Ripple>   ); }  export default Button;`

Comment: This is the component I am calling

Comment: @AdamSchwarcz Alright, but you have the conditionals in a different component (Ripple) so that will not work for its parent (Button).

Comment: Button is the child component rendered in the parent. The ripple is just a div inside the Button components (the child)

Comment: @AdamSchwarcz bro I am confused. Tell me exactly what are you trying to do, and include all relevant code

Comment: The child: 
`
const Ripple = styled(ButtonBase)`
  font-family: ${font.family};
  color: white !important;

  &:focus {
    border-radius: 6px;
  }
`;

  &:hover {
    background: ${color.action_70};
  }
`;

function Button(props) {
  return (
    <Ripple href={props.href} focusRipple>
      <Box>{props.label}</Box>
    </Ripple>
  );
}`

Comment: The parent:
`function Navigation() {
  return (
    <Nav>
          <Item
            label="Featured Projects"
            icon={<Star color={color.yellow_100} size="16" strokeWidth="3" />}
            href="/"
          />
          <Item
            label="Adam's folders"
            icon={<Folder color={color.red_100} size="16" strokeWidth="3" />}
            href="/"
          />
          <Divider />
          <Item label="Resumé" href="/" />
          <Button small label="Get in touch" href="/" />
</Nav>
  );`

Comment: I want to be able to change the size of button with props from parent by calling either <Button sm/> or <Button md/> or <Button lg/>